# wordpress site with latin-ext characters shows empty boxes instead of latin-ext chars on mobile browsers

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

everything's fine with desktop displays. I just checked it from my mobile, however, and I get something akin to `U+2599` instead of š, đ, ć, č and ž everywhere! Why?

this is how I call on the fonts in mz functions.php

```
<?php
// Add your custom functions here excluded:    |Roboto+Slab:400,300,700&subset=latin,latin-ext


function sparkling_google_fonts() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'sparkling-fonts' );
    wp_register_style( 'sparkling-googele-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600|Oswald:700|Roboto+Slab:400,300,700&subset=latin,latin-ext');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sparkling_google_fonts' );


?>
```

any and all help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that many mobile devices don't have complete font sets installed. There is nothing you can do except avoid these characters.

Comment: well, that's just swell. :( Thank you very much for your answer.